# Skip a level in nested list

Tags: lists, nesting

I'd like a nested itemize environment like this:

> ·1
>   ____·1.1
>   _________·comments on 1.1
>   ·2
>   _________·comments on 2

The second comment has a format of the third level itemize, same as the first comment. But I can't skip a level of nested itemize by doing some like:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item 2
  \begin{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item comments on 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

That will cause a "missing \item" error. Also I can't do this by merely adjusting indentation, since I want the list in beamer and there are many other style differences between the levels.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can add an item by `\item[]`. However it not really clear what do you want to achieve. Maybe you need a new list (see package `enumitem`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use [easylist](/questions/tagged/easylist)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{easylist}
\begin{document}
    \begin{easylist}[itemize]
        § 1
            §§ 1.1
                §§§ comments on 1.1
        § 2
                §§§ comments on 2
    \end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem over at overleaf, but the compiler still gives me a pdf. It does inform me of the error, however, the pdf is exactly like I want it. I guess one possibility is to just ignore the error.